# Channels.newChanne() will help to achieve actual ZeroCopy

Tags: java, zero-copy

I have some doubt regarding using Channels.newChannel(OutputStream/InputStream) in zeroCopy operation. Will it serve as zeroCopy. I have some restriction like have to send 1st header part(file and user related information) then file content.
For testing, i also override BufferedOutputStream, but on fileChannel.transferTo call, it is calling my override methods...
Please help me how to achieve zeroCopy in such circumstances(header+content).

part of testing code:

```
String host = "127.0.0.1";
SocketAddress sad = new InetSocketAddress(host, ZeroCopyServer.PORT);
Socket s=new Socket();
s.connect(sad);

OutputStream o=s.getOutputStream();
OutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(o);
WritableByteChannel ch=Channels.newChannel(o);
//can i use
//WritableByteChannel ch=Channels.newChannel(out);

String msg="Hi how are you and what are you doing...";
out.write(msg.getBytes());
out.flush();

String fname = "hello.txt";
String fname2 = "input";
long fileSize = new File(fname).length();

FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fname).getChannel();
FileChannel fc2 = new FileInputStream(fname2).getChannel();

fc.transferTo(0, fc.size(), ch);
fc2.transferTo(0, fc2.size(), ch);

fc.close();
fc2.close();
out.close();
ch.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Will it serve as zeroCopy.

No. You would have to start with a `SocketChannel` for that, not a `Socket,` and use it directly in `transferTo()`.

> I have some restriction like have to send 1st header part(file and user related information)

Well you can't do that with zero copy.

> then file content.

That part you can achieve.

Note that `transferTo()` isn't specified to do the entire transfer in a single call. You have to loop, noting the return value and adjusting the offset accordingly until it's all done.

Comment: Thanks EJP.
My problem is : have to use single stream/channel for both header and content. I will try to solve with nio socketChannel.
I m thinking, for header part will send using socketChannel->socket->outputstream then flush output stream after that same socketChannel will use as argument for FileChannel.transferTo. will get back, if got any problem.
meanwhile, please suggest me if this is not a correct way to solve this problem...

Comment: With socket we can set timeout for connection as well for read/write. Is this possible for SocketChannel? Then how?

Comment: First, forget about the output streams. Use ByteBuffer to send your headers. Second, you can achieve a connect timeout via SocketChannel.socket().connect().